# Graphical difference between $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=(x,x^2)$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Graphically speaking what is the difference between:

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x^2$, and

$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g(x)=(x,x^2)$?

I know that $f$ just looks like a parabola $P=\{(x,y):y=x^2\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but doesn't the second also look like that since the function $g$ would just be returning to each point point $x$ on the $x$-axis, the point $(x,x^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But it seems obviously wrong that they would be the same. I have read that for any function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the graph of $f$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so I assume for $g$ the graph should actually be in 3-dimensions but why would we need the $z$-axis?

Similarly wouldn't the graph $h:P\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x,x^2)=x$ just be the same parabola as $f$ but to each point $(x,x^2)$ of the parabola it returns the value on the $x$-axis. Why would this need to be 3-dimensional. I think I'm getting myself mixed up between functions and curves and can't stop confusing myself! I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The graph of $g$ is $\Gamma(g) = \{(x, x, x^2) : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ by definition. The question of why we "need" the extra axis is moot; you're confusing "graph" with "range." The graph of the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$ is the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas the range of the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There's also the notion of "parametric curves". Possibly, you are also confusing graphs and parametric curves with each other.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thank you for replying. So is it right to say that the function $g$ is "in 3-dimensions" but the range or image is the parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I suppose my confusion is that for $g$ we would visualise the range, but for $f$ we'd visualise the function?

Comment: @zipirovich Yes I think so! My confusion started after I looked at the parametric equation for the circle $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$ and so for this, we'd only visualise the range/image (the circle) rather than visualising the function itself?

Comment: Yes, exactly! What we visualize by parametric equations is the range, not the graph. (And I wouldn't use the phrase "visualizing the *function itself*", as it's unclear what it means.) To make matters worse, i.e. more confusing, textbooks commonly speak of "the graph of a parametric function" or "the graph of parametric equations", even though it is not a *graph* in the usual (more rigorous) sense.

Comment: @zipirovich That helps a lot, thank you!